# Find duplicate value in a column, and check from another one to delete the recent rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a excel vba table where I can find some duplicate value in columns 'I'.
I need to delete the last duplicate rows (This one who didn't had manual data added).
For doing that I created a column in "CF" with the date where the rows was created.
So I need to delete duplicate data in column 'I' where the date is the most recent.

Exemple :
Row 1 column 'I' : 9095-IDE
Row 1 column 'CF' : 21/06/23 14:50:16

Row 2 column 'I' : 9095-IDE
Row 2 column 'CF' : 26/06/23 14:45:42

Then Row 2 would be delete.
That work, but sometime I don't know why, it will be row 1 who will be delete.
That shit cause in a lot column between I & CF, user need to write manual data in.. So if I delete the wrong one, they lost their data...

Here my VBA macro :

```
Sub supprimerDoublons()
    Dim derniereligne As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim a As Long
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim rngToDelete As Range
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    derniereligne = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For a = 5 To derniereligne
        x = Cells(a, "I").Value
        If Not dict.exists(x) Then
            dict.Add x, a
        Else
            If Cells(a, "CF").Value > Cells(dict(x), "CF").Value Then
                If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngToDelete = Rows(a)
                Else
                    Set rngToDelete = Union(rngToDelete, Rows(a))
                End If
            Else
                If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngToDelete = Rows(dict(x))
                Else
                    Set rngToDelete = Union(rngToDelete, Rows(dict(x)))
                End If
                dict.Item(x) = a
            End If
        End If
    Next a
    
    If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
        rngToDelete.Delete
    End If
    
End Sub
```

It will run on rows, stock a value in dictionnary. If a same value is already in dictionnary, it will check in CF the date and stock in rngToDelete the right one to delete.

In paper, it look amazing, but can't find why sometime it didn't work well, and delete the wrong row ...

Can someone help me ?

I tried many thing, but I can't replicate the bug everytime, it like random ..
Would like to know if anyone had similare trouble, or have another solutions ..

Answer (score 2):

### Delete 'Duplicate' Rows: Keep the First (Top-Most) Smallest Value in a Column

**A Quick Fix**

- Your *If* statement is wrong because it doesn't cover the case when the cells in column `CF` are equal which is falling under the *Else* statement in your code. To correct this, use:

  ```
  If Cells(a, "CF").Value >= Cells(dict(x), "CF").Value Then
  ```

[image]

**An Improvement**

- Use more variables and a function to combine the cells to vastly improve the code's readability.
- Qualify all ranges, cells, rows, and columns with the correct worksheet so the code would work if you would (correctly) specify the worksheet with e.g. `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`, not relying on the active sheet.

```vb
Sub DeleteDuplicateRows()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' i.e. 'A = a'
    
    Dim rngToDelete As Range, NewValue, PreviousValue, sStr As String
    Dim r As Long, pr As Long
    
    For r = 5 To LastRow
        sStr = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "I").Value)
        If Not dict.Exists(sStr) Then
            dict(sStr) = r
        Else
            pr = dict(sStr)
            PreviousValue = ws.Cells(pr, "CF").Value
            NewValue = ws.Cells(r, "CF").Value
            If NewValue >= PreviousValue Then
                Set rngToDelete = RefCombinedRange(rngToDelete, ws.Rows(r))
            Else
                dict(sStr) = r
                Set rngToDelete = RefCombinedRange(rngToDelete, ws.Rows(pr))
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
        ' Test with:
        rngToDelete.Select
        ' When done testing, use the following instead.
        'rngToDelete.Delete xlShiftUp
    End If
    
End Sub

Function RefCombinedRange(ByVal urg As Range,ByVal arg As Range) As Range
    If urg Is Nothing Then Set urg = arg Else Set urg = Union(urg, arg)
    Set RefCombinedRange = urg
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, tanks a lot for your answer, I will improve my code following your exemple.

I have question on this : Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"), not relying on the active sheet.

Is it really important to use activesheet ? I mean, it's not suppose to be used on the activesheet anyway ? (I'm novice sorry if it's an obvious thing..)

Comment: It is bad to use `ActiveSheet` but it's better than nothing. If you set it at the beginning of the code, you can easily change it to a specific worksheet in one single place and the code will work correctly (see `ws.Cells(...)`, `ws.Rows(...)`, etc.). If the worksheet is in the workbook containing this code, definitely use `ThisWorkbook`. If you know the worksheet name (you most often do) then specify as prescribed. If you just use `Cells` (bad) instead of `ws.Cells` (good), it will refer to the active sheet and who knows if it will be the correct one (the selected one) when the code runs.

Comment: Alright, I see, thank for explaining me that. 

Also have another question, actually got filtre on the sheet, on 4th rows, and I got stuck cause when filtre are not select, some rows are not delete, I tried :

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter

but that make my 4 first row to be delete, and not sure it work, what can I do to improve code with opening every filtre on my sheet ?

Comment: After you set the worksheet, use `If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData ' clear filters`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! that's work ! 
Now I'm looking for saving filtre before clearing them & reapply them after I deleted duplicate rows :D 
Will work on that !

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this :

```
Sub supprimerDoublons()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    'Les filtres
    Dim filterRange As Range
    Dim filterCriteria As Variant

    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
    ' Mémoriser la plage et les critères de filtre existants
    Set filterRange = ws.AutoFilter.Range
    filterCriteria = ws.AutoFilter.Filters
    
    ws.ShowAllData ' Effacer les filtres

    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' i.e. 'A = a'
    
    Dim rngToDelete As Range, NewValue, PreviousValue, sStr As String
    Dim r As Long, pr As Long
    
    For r = 5 To LastRow
        sStr = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "I").Value)
        If Not dict.Exists(sStr) Then
            dict(sStr) = r
        Else
            pr = dict(sStr)
            PreviousValue = ws.Cells(pr, "CF").Value
            NewValue = ws.Cells(r, "CF").Value
            If NewValue >= PreviousValue Then
                Set rngToDelete = RefCombinedRange(rngToDelete, ws.Rows(r))
            Else
                dict(sStr) = r
                Set rngToDelete = RefCombinedRange(rngToDelete, ws.Rows(pr))
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
        ' Test with:
        'rngToDelete.Select
        'When done testing, use the following instead.
        rngToDelete.Delete xlShiftUp
    End If
    
        ' Rétablir les filtres précédents
    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=filterCriteria(5)
    ' Répétez cette ligne pour chaque colonne avec des filtres, en ajustant l'index de la colonne et du critère si nécessaire
    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=filterCriteria(7)
    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=filterCriteria(8)
End If
    
End Sub

Function RefCombinedRange(ByVal urg As Range, ByVal arg As Range) As Range
    If urg Is Nothing Then Set urg = arg Else Set urg = Union(urg, arg)
    Set RefCombinedRange = urg
End Function
```

But I got an error 450 on execution, can't find why ..

Comment: Still stuck on it.. Released a version without filter reapplied.
Looking for any suggestions on this. Ty very much